# Are the names of historic events treated as proper nouns?

Tags: capitalization, proper-nouns

When writing about famous events, how are they capitalised? As a proper name? It is obvious that World War 1 and the Second World War are capitalized. But what about, for example, the Cuban Missile Crisis, or is it the Cuban missile crisis?

Comment: When in doubt, [look it up](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cuban_missile_crisis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When specifying certain historical eras, or historical periods, and when referring to specific historical events, they should be capitalized as proper nouns. Doing this differentiates these titles or names from the common words within them.

For example:

1. Roaring Twenties
2. McCarthy Era
3. Cold War
4. Bronze Age
5. Great Depression

Comment: Yes I agree. I think if using capitals I would tend to put "Roaring Twenties" in inverted commas - not everyone calls them that. It is not such a recognised historical term as, for example the Cold War. But certainly for things like "the Reformation", or "the French Revolution", or "the American War of Independence" I would simply capitalise, without quotation marks.